# Dynamically add image view in Custom cell and assign image to it

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am facing lots of problem.. i am new to ios development so any help is appreciated.

[image: dyanamic imageview]
Problem 1st

I want to display N number of image-view+label over yellow and blue image In custom cell.

I have to parse that how many Number of Image view will be shown on every row and according to that i have to assign image to every image-view in my custom cell. how can i do that?
I fetch image links from database and store it into array but how can i apply links to particular image-view in row.

Just need hints to build above User Interface in iOS.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifierLeft = @"lefthand";
static NSString *CellIdentifierRight = @"righthand";

if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) // to get two custom cell vice versa.
{
  LeftCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierLeft];


    if (LeftCell == nil)
   { 
        LeftCell = [[customCellLeft alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierLeft row:indexPath.row];


         LeftCell.scrollView  = [[cellScrollViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,14,1024,187)];


    }
      LeftCell.videoImageView1.tag=[ImageLinkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       LeftCell.label1.text=[TitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return LeftCell;
}
  else
{

RightCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierRight];


if(RightCell == nil)
{

    RightCell =[[customCellRight alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierRight];

   RightCell.scrollView  = [[cellScrollViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,14,1024,187)];


    }
      RightCell.videoImageView1.tag=[ImageLinkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       RightCell.label1.text=[TitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return RightCell;
}
```

Custom cell class code...

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier row:(int)row
 {
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {

    int indexNumber; // variable to store Array index number

    int VideoNumber=3; // imageview in particular cell + Train Engine.


   scrollView  = [[cellScrollViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33,14,958,187)]; // Scrollview 
    scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((335*VideoNumber),187); // To make ContentSize for item to scroll
      for (int i = 0; i < VideoNumber; i++)
    { // for loop to add 2 wagon view and 1 engine view on Left hand side Custom cell.

        if(i==0) // to check first item must be train Engine
        {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            frame.origin.y = 18;
            frame.size.width=186;
            frame.size.height= 162;

            UIView *EngineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            UIImageView *engineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 6, 186, 162)];
            UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loco_left.png"];
            engineImageView.image = Image;
            [EngineView addSubview:engineImageView];
            [scrollView addSubview:EngineView];  // add 1st imageview that is Train Engine to first of scrollview
        }
        else

        { // else it must be wagon of train.

            indexNumber=row*(VideoNumber-1)+(i-1);// to get Index Number of array to to display Images as per cell number

            NSLog(@"at Normal row index number is %d",indexNumber);
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = (385*i)-432;
            frame.origin.y = 18;
            frame.size.width=385;
            frame.size.height= 163;

            UIView *wagon = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            UIImageView *wagonImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 6, 385, 163)];
            UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wagon_left.png"];
            wagonImage.image = Image;
            [wagon addSubview:wagonImage];


            UIView *videoviewContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 190 , 200)];

            videoImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 190, 100)];
            UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"];
            videoImageView2.image = bgImage;
            videoviewContainer.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft; // set Video Image view to left hand side of wagon UIView
            videoImageView2.tag=indexNumber;

            [videoviewContainer addSubview:videoImageView2];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *video = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(VideoItemOne:)];
            [videoImageView2 addGestureRecognizer:video];



            [videoImageView2 setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
            [videoImageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            UIView *textUiView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(208,28, 150 , 187)];
            textUiView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
            label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28,10, 150 , 87)];
            label2.text=[TitleArray objectAtIndex:indexNumber];
            label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label2.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
            label2.numberOfLines = 4;
            [textUiView addSubview:label2];

            [wagonImage addSubview:textUiView];
            [wagonImage addSubview:videoviewContainer];

            [scrollView addSubview:wagon];

        }
    }


    [self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
     }
return self;
  }
-(void)populateWithImage:myImage andText:myText
{
[videoImageView2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myImage]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"]];
  }
```

Comment: Please separate your questions into different posts.  This will make it easier for the community to answer your questions.

Comment: @JeffWolski Ok i will edit the 2nd question..and after i got 1st answer i will post 2nd one

Comment: When you have to create different cells, you can still reuse cells by having a reset funtion which will clear subviews and then style them according to requirement.

Comment: @PraveenS can you please tell me how can i add N number of image view in cell and how can i assign image to that particular imageview in cell??

Comment: I am unable to get you exact problem but i will give a try assuming you want to show N images in N cells with each cell having different images. Also i can see that your background images keep alernating. So it should be real easy to do it. So is what i understand rite?

Comment: Why are you assigning tag of the imageview to the value returned from objectAtIndex?

Comment: @PraveenS yes you are right I want to display N number of images in cell and each having different images..and i have to change train engine left of right vice vera according to number of row.. and i used tag to imageview because i when touchgesturerecognizer called i will come to know which image is clicked..by using gesture.view.tag

Answer (score 0):

Your custom cell should have the following: (note, you have to use a better naming convention and i am just giving an example)

- Background Imageview (bgImage)
- Main image View (mainImage)
- UI Label (mainLabel)

In the init for this cell, based on the indexpath.row, either assign the left or right train image.

Also set the frames for main image view and the label.

```
        MYCustomCell * cell;

        if(indexPath.row %2)
        {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"OddCell"];
            if (cell == nil)
             { 
                cell = [[MYCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierLeft row:indexPath.row];
             }
        }
        else {
             cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"EvenCell"];
            if (cell == nil)
             { 
                cell = [[MYCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierLeft row:indexPath.row];
             }
        }


    [cell populateWithImage:myImage andText:myText]; //myImage and myText are to be gotten from the data source which in your case is ImageLinkArray and TitleArray
return cell;
```

Comment: [cell populateWithImage:myImage andText:myText]; This will only set One image-view and one label of cell..i want every image-view has to assign different images according to array index

Comment: It will be called for every cell created and if you change image and text for every index, it will be reflected.

Comment: Ok I will try this and i have to crate populateWithImage method in my custom cell and assign image link and title from populateWithImage method right?

Comment: I tried your solution but it just fill the last created Image-view in row..I am going to add code of custom cell on main question

Comment: Ok do that, we can take it from there.

Comment: The placeholder image is the same always and hence you cannot see any change. Have you verified if the url which you are using to set videoImageView2 is valid image?

Comment: I dont understand about placeholder..and what updating i need to do in cellForRowIndexpath method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30492/discussion-between-praveen-s-and-swapandroid)

Comment: understand your logic to store view object into mutable array but it doesnt work at all in my case..it builds and after 0th index it crashes and display array index out of bound ...it means array is not able to fill with objects..